# show/hide components based on roles

Tags: angular

I have a dashboard component that will be serving different profiles. For each profile I created a separate component and added it to the main dashboard component :

```
**dashboard.component.html**

<app-employer-dashboard></app-employer-dashboard>
<app-candidate-dashboard></app-candidate-dashboard>
```

What i want to achieve is similar to auth guards for routes, add some decoration, so that based on the user profile, activate only the corresponding component.
using `[hidden]="hasNotAccessToComponent()"` seems to be possible but i am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Well, there is also `*ngIf` but not sure it fits your _"elegant way"_.

Comment: correct me if am wrong, *ngIf loads the element and then comment if the value is evaluated to false ?

Comment: @badrslaoui you can also use `NgSwitchCase` or as @Lafexlos is said use `*ngIf`.

Comment: @badrslaoui if `*ngIf` is false content not load in `DOM`

Comment: I recommend setting it in your router with `canActivate` property using `route Guards`

Comment: I suggest you to use `canActivate()` and/or `canActivateChild()` of route guard. Relying on `*ngIf` may lead vulnerabilites. These two articles may help you : [1](https://scotch.io/courses/routing-angular-2-applications/canactivate-and-canactivatechild) , [2](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-route-guards-canactivate-and-canactivatechild-example)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend setting it in your router with `canActivate` property using `route Guards` as follows -

So, your routes would be -

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'employer',
        component: EmployerDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
        path: 'candidate',
        component: CandidateDashboardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
];
```

Your `canActivate` method in ***[AuthGuard](https://angular.io/guide/router)*** would be similar to the following -

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    const currentUser = this.userService.getCurrentUser();
    this.currentUserRole = currentUser ? JSON.parse(currentUser)['role'] : undefined;
    this.currentUserRole = this.currentUserRole ? this.currentUserRole.toLowerCase() : undefined;

    // I stored allowed paths with the same user object
    let allowedPaths = currentUser ? JSON.parse(currentUser)['allowedPaths'] : undefined;

    // obtaining an array of strings for allowed paths
    this.allowedPaths = allowedPaths ? allowedPaths.split(",").map(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim) : undefined;
    const isLoggedIn = this.userService.isLoggedIn();
    if(isLoggedIn) {
        if (this.currentUserRole == 'admin') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return this.validatePath(this.allowedPaths, state.url);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the method I used to `validatePath` is as follows -

```
validatePath(pathArray: Array <string>, path: string): boolean {
    if(!pathArray) {
        return false;
    }

    if(pathArray.includes(path)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['inaccessible']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to keep the same path, both 'dashboard', rather than 'employer' and 'candidate' and use different guards ?

Comment: yeah, you could easily achieve the same. please read the official doc I mentioned in the link above so that you will find a way to it!